# Is it possible to allow users that are not real user in a Ubuntu distro that runs the SAMBA server to access its shared-folders?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba

According to [`Samba/SambaServerGuide`-->`File Sharing (Basics)`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide):

> NOTE: the username used here should be a real user setup on your
> PC/Server.

What if I don't have these user names created on the Ubuntu machine that runs the SAMBA server? Is there a way to allow such users to access the shared-folders on the SAMBA server? These users already have access to the same local network running the SAMBA server via their own laptops and they don't need to have a user account on the Ubuntu machine that runs the SAMBA server.

I tried to add these users to SAMBA like so:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a username_not_in_machine_running_samba_server
```

However, it failed. Got msg `Failed to add entry for user username_not_in_machine_running_samba_server`.

In the Ubuntu distro, there is already the user `samba_guest_account`

[image: samba_guest_account]

Also, guest access (for people without a user account) has been enabled when creating the shared folder.

[image: Shared folder properties]

Error msg from trying to access the shared folder:

> Fail to mount Window share. Permission denied.

and

> The specified location is not mounted.

Comment: If you have a user called 'samba_guest_account' then even though it has 'guest' in the name, it isn't a guest user, it is a normal account, the guest user in Samba does not work like that. The Samba guest works by having 'map to guest = bad user' in global and 'guest ok = yes' in the share. once set up, any unknown users connecting to Samba will be mapped to the guest user (usually 'nobody') and allowed access to the guest share. 'unknown' means any users you haven't created as Samba users on the server.,

Comment: In addition, you have configured samba shares two different ways in your question: a "classic" share in smb.conf and a "usershare" from Nautilus. If they are sharing the same folder you may be ending up with a mess. I would suggest adding the output of 2 commands to your original question to clear things up: `net usershare info --long` , `testparm -s`